# Using canvas to layer animated and static content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have the fireworks from https://codepen.io/haidang/pen/WRGXJv overlaying the interactive table+button from https://codepen.io/kimaro/pen/BjqYeo.

I have tried using two canvases, where the canvas for the fireworks has

```
z-index=1
```

and the canvas for the table+button has

```
z-index=0
```

I tried changing the following in fireworks.js:

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#000'; //old
ctx.fillstyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' //full transparent background
```

however the table+button canvas doesn't show for me. additionally, when changing the `fillstyle`s for `fillrect` methods to be transparent, the background of the firework canvas changes colour randomly.

Additionally, if I call the firework js at the end of my html, then I can't click on the button of the canvas layer underneath.

Edit: As has been pointed out by Archer, the button would have to be on the top canvas layer. In this case, the background of the table+button layer would have to be transparent, whilst the layer underneath has the desired background colour.

Edit 2: A friend suggested I could merge the layers, to overcome the issue of the button being on the layer below.

Comment: You won't be able to click a canvas that's behind another one - the button has to be at the front.

Comment: Use colons (`:`) for css properties